# Convert project in existing workspace from ADT to Andmore

Tags: eclipse, adt, andmore

I have just updated from Eclipse Luna to Eclipse Oxygen and installed Andmore. I have a bunch of project workspaces which were created with Eclipse Luna and ADT.

Eclipse automatically upgrades workspaces to the newer version on import, but it doesn’t convert from ADT to Andmore (which, although sharing much of the same code, is a different plugin).

Is there a way I can migrate an existing Eclipse workspace from ADT to Andmore without having to delete and re-import every single Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an official way, see [here](https://github.com/eclipse/andmore/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-importconvert-an-existing-adt-project-to-work-with-andmore). This needs to be done for each project in the workspace (also for library projects, if any):

- Right-click the project, then select **Configure > Convert to Andmore Project** (wording of the last menu item may differ slightly).
- In my case I had to restart Eclipse before it would pick up everything.
- You may also need to clean your project.

If you had any tabs with ADT-specific views open (which includes all ADT files and potentially anything which is not a Java source file), you will need to close and reopen them, as they still refer to ADT components which are no longer available. Closing and reopening them will bring up the corresponding Andmore view.

<del>I still get an error message when I try to build the app, but that may be unrelated.</del> The first build failed with an error but that was due to a separate, unrelated issue.